# How can I create a table from answers in a Google Form, in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-forms

So I'm really new to JavaScript, and I've been trying to organise, in a automated way, the answers that I get from a Google Form in a Google Sheet.

I need to organise it in a table, with categories as lines and dates as rows, and with every new answer I need that table to updates itself. The date could only update once a day, and if a person answers in that day, the answer would fall on the row of that day, and on the line of the category that the person chose, and in the cell that cross's both of them an 'X'.

I know how to work the update part with triggers in Google's AppScript, but I don't know how to design the table.

If somebody could help me, even if with the most basic table design, I would really appreciate it.

Here's my sample spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zgqldnuXHWGe6LImgfg3nJGyUfNZAd6P1Q1RP-GlYXY/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you

What I've done to organise a little the answears I got:

```
function check_data() {

  var num_rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName("Respostas do Formulário 1")
    .getLastRow();

  for (i = 2; i < num_rows + 1; i++) {

    var colA = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getSheetByName("Respostas do Formulário 1")
      .getRange("A" + i)
      .getValue()
    var colB = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getSheetByName("Respostas do Formulário 1")
      .getRange("B" + i)
      .getValue()
    var colC = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getSheetByName("Respostas do Formulário 1")
      .getRange("C" + i)
      .getValue()
    var colD = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getSheetByName("Respostas do Formulário 1")
      .getRange("D" + i)
      .getValue()
    var colE = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getSheetByName("Respostas do Formulário 1")
      .getRange("E" + i)
      .getValue()

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getSheetByName("script")
      .getRange("A" + i)
      .setValue(colA)

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getSheetByName("script")
      .getRange("B" + i)
      .setValue(colB)

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getSheetByName("script")
      .getRange("C" + i)
      .setValue(colC)

    if (colD == 0) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
        .getSheetByName("script")
        .getRange("D" + i)
        .setValue(colE)
    } else {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
        .getSheetByName("script")
        .getRange("D" + i)
        .setValue(colD)
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what have to tried so far?
And also it will be helpful to share an sample sheet with some sharable data and the expected output so that it is easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). What you are asking sounds doable with plain vanilla spreadsheet formulas without resorting to scripting. You may want to try `query()` with the `pivot` clause. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: So, because the form puts the various categories in different columns, the only thing I've done so far, and with the help of a friend, was putting it all in one column, so that it was easier to read. But I'm not sure if that was necessary to this part, to be honest. But I'm gonna put it on the post.

Comment: Alright, I'm gonna do the Google Test Sheet

Comment: Sample Spreadsheet created and added to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest an easier approach.

You can use a Pivot with calculated field.
So add a Pivot to your data with the following parameters:

Data range - `'Answears From Google Form'!A1:C`

Rows - Sort by `Category`

Columns - Sort by `Date`

Values - Calculated Field, Formula - `=Email`, Summarize by - `Custom`

You can uncheck the Show totals for Rows and Columns and Filter Category to remove blanks and it should work as the desired output in your sheet.

[image]

Comment: I've tried this, but I can't put one date in one column like you did. And I don't have the custom option on Values - Email... Can you help me with that?

Comment: Ok, It worked on the SampleSheet (just couldn't put the word 'email' on the cells) but not on the real one.
And is this table updated automatically?

Comment: Can you share edit access to your sheet and I can try to troubleshoot?

Comment: On the SampleSheet? Sure

Comment: Done. Seems to be working now. Let me know if this is what you wanted?

Comment: How did you do that?! xD

Comment: I added a calculated field in the pivot table vs the one that was present. Does this work for you now?

Comment: And is there any way to make sure that the dates will be together?

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do you mean by having dates 'together'?

Comment: On my real spreadsheet, If I have more than one answer on one specific date, the date will appear as many times as the number of answers on that date

Comment: If it is a different category then it will work exactly as you's asked in the question. The intersection of the unique date and unique category will show the relevant value. Could you update your sample sheet with this new use case data and I can then better understand the query?

Comment: Ok, so what I have now in the Sample Spreadshit is pretty much the same as the real one. I have the three main columns with: Date, Email and Category (these three come from the answers of the Google Form) and another column with the total of categorys.

Comment: I can see that the pivot table method is working. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's working on the sample, but it isn't on the real one, because it doesn't group the dates, and I dont think it updates automatically

Comment: Why don't you show where it is not working by adding those cases to the sample data? Also this is a pivot table in the range A1:C1000 so it will update automatically when you add something in the range.

Comment: So, I think I found out why it doesn't group the same date, on the same column. It's because on the sheet that it gets the info from, altough on cell it only appears the date, on you click on it, it appears the date and the hour

Comment: I got the dates to group, but it doesn't seem to want to update. The last answer that I got was on the 30th but the table only goes until the 28th.

Comment: Where are you seeing this? The sheet that you've linked above is showing a different view.

Answer (score -1):

It would be easier to make use of the `Data -> Pivot table` feature.

1. Click `Data -> Pivot table`.
2. In the "Create pivot table" dialog, fill in the ff. values:

   - **Data range**: `'your_sheet_name'!1:1000`
   - **Insert to**: "New sheet"
3. On the "Pivot table editor", add ff. values:

   - **Rows**: "Category"
   - **Columns**: "Date"
   - **Values**: (Click "Add" then select "Calculated Field")

     - Formula: `=TO_TEXT(Email)` (this is to show the email value)
     - Summarize by: Custom
     - Show as: Default

[image: Pivot table]

---

## **A side note to your script though (just a tip, not an answer).**

I noticed you were repeating several things: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Respostas do Formulário 1")` and `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("script")`. Your code would be cleaner by breaking those into variables, i.e.:

```
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var form1 = activeSheet.getSheetByName('Respostas do Formulário 1');
var scriptSheet = activeSheet.getSheetByName('script');
```

Then you can reuse those variables like so:

```
var colA = form1.getRange("A" + i).getValue();
var colB = form1.getRange("B" + i).getValue();
var colC = form1.getRange("C" + i).getValue();
var colD = form1.getRange("D" + i).getValue();
var colE = form1.getRange("E" + i).getValue();

scriptSheet.getRange("A" + i).setValue(colA);
scriptSheet.getRange("B" + i).setValue(colB);
scriptSheet.getRange("C" + i).setValue(colC);
scriptSheet.getRange("D" + i).setValue(colD);
scriptSheet.getRange("E" + i).setValue(colE);
```

Comment: the emails continue not to show up and the table doesn't update with new answers, but the code looks cleaner

Comment: @AndréFilipe, the code was just a "tip", not an actual answer. It's coding practice.

Comment: @AndréFilipe, your code isn't working at all. Changing your code into what I suggested wouldn't make it work.